# Sign In GitHub Enterprise via LDAP fails due to change username

Tags: git, logging, authentication, github, ldap

My company hosts a github internal site using LDAP to authenticate, and uses the company's database as login credentials. Everything works fine until I change the username of the account through the link:

```
git.xxx.com/account/rename_box
```

Then I change the username, and I am still able to view the github page through:

`git.xxx.com/newusername`

However, now I can't log in via LDAP, it shows invalid login and remind me that my company email account has been taken

So what can I do? 
Is sending email to the administrator to change and reconfigure the username the only solution or I can change the odds by myself through some ways?

Comment: Not being familiar with Github Enterprise but knowing how most LDAP bindings tend to work, I'm inclined to say you're going to have to talk to the administrator.

Comment: Thanks for advice, do contact the admin and able to log in now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by contacting the git admin by reverting the username back to the original